# Structure of folder for uploaded files

Tags: php, file, upload, directory

I am implementing a website which allows users to upload their files. I wonder how the upload folder should be structured so that I can manage the uploaded files easily in the future. Should I provide different users with different sub-folders (for example, upload/user1 for user1, upload/user2 for user2, etc.) or should I just put them all in the same folder? And should I rename the uploaded files? (I know that a lot of websites do this!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you won't be using BLOB, and the users may have an arbitrary number of images, then I think you should be using the subfolders. For instance, you could create a subfolder named after the user's id. One of the reasons for this is that when the folder contains A LOT of files, the access times increase as it takes more time to find the file with specified name. You could also rename the files when they're stored just so that there would be no chance of their names overlapping. Just don't forget to store the newly-generated names in the DB.

Comment: I came across a solution, which tells me to structure my upload folder as following: The main folder is called `upload`, which consists of 3 levels (for example: `upload/0/0/file.jpg`). When folder `upload/0/0` is filled with 1024 files, folder `upload/0/1` is created automatically. Folder `upload/0` can have 1024 sub-folders (`upload/0/0` to `upload/0/1023`). Similarly, folder `upload` can have 1024 sub-folders too. Therefore, at maximum, we can store 2^30 files. If each day, users upload a total of 1024 files, it will take them 2873 years to use up the space. Do you think it is feasible?

Comment: I think it could be better to do something like this: name the first-level subdirectory by the user's id. The next step is valid only if you assign a unique id to each image the user uploaded. Then you could try naming the second-level subdirectory as strval($imgId % DIVISOR_CHOSEN_BY_YOU). In some cases this may cut back on the number of images in each subdirectory, I think. Note that I'm far from expert in this, though...

Answer (score 0):

Renaming them can be useful if you ever want to "hide" them to anyone not logged in, for example. Just store their original name in a DB.

Also, you can always store it all in a SQL table in a BLOB type.. Can be several GB and lets you relate a filename, username, whatever else.

Comment: A co-worker once told me that I should not use BLOB type because it could enlarge the db unnecessarily. Anyway, thanks for your answer about the purpose of file renaming though I am still confused about the location for the uploaded files

Comment: It will enlarge the DB, but using files will enlarge the directory, so what's your point? It won't slow it down at all.